# Convert matrix to cell array of cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I want to change a matrix N*123456 to a cells of cells, each sub-cell contains a N*L matrix

Eg:

```
matrixSize= 50*123456
N=50
L=100
```

Output will be 1*1235 cell and each cell has a 50*L matrix (last cell has only 50*56)

I know there is a function mat2cell in matlab:

```
Output = mat2cell(x, [50], [100,100,100,......56])
```

But it doesn't sound an intuitive solution.

So is there a good solution?

Comment: Your example matrix sizes are inconsistent.  I don't see how the output can be achieved that way with your example parameters.  Also, what exactly is a "cell trunk"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, assuming your matrix is denoted `m`, this is what you wanted:

```
a=num2cell(reshape(m(:,1:size(m,2)-mod(size(m,2),L)),N*L,[]),1);
a=cellfun(@(n) reshape(n,N,L), a,'UniformOutput',false);
a{end+1}=m(:,end-mod(size(m,2),L)+1:end);
```

(this can be shortened to a single line if you wish)...
Lets test with some minimal numbers:

```
m=rand(50,334);
N=50; 
L=100;
```

yields:

```
a = 
[50x100 double]    [50x100 double]    [50x100 double]    [50x34 double]
```

note that I didn't check for the exact dimension in the reshape, so you may need to reshape to `...,[],N*L)` etc.

Comment: for the sake of completeness this is the one line solution: `a=[cellfun(@(n) reshape(n,N,L), num2cell(reshape(m(:,1:size(m,2)-mod(size(m,2),L)),N*L,[]),1),'un',0) ,{m(:,end-mod(size(m,2),L)+1:end)}];
`

Comment: +1 - You took a rather incomprehensible question and clarified with your answer.  Very cool!

Answer (score 2):

Just use elementary maths.

```
q = floor(123456/100);
r = rem(123456,100);
Output = mat2cell(x, 50, [repmat(100,1,q),r])
```